# Get total height of child elements to duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed position `#header` with an X of `.child` elements in it with a height of 19px and hidden overflow. The `#header` has a `:hover` which changes the height to `max-height` (so it expands with the .child elements in it) and with a animation `transition: max-height 0.2s 1s ease;`. (fixed divs can't manipulate divs around as it grows or shrinks), so I would like to make a `position: relative` div below `#header` that has the same content height as `#header` that grows or shrinks the same time as `#header:hover` but can move the other divs below it with animation.

I found a way on other posts on Stackoverflow that nearly did the trick [see JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/807/4bre330q/1/), except that it counts all the heights of the .child elements together. I only need the height of the `#parent` but that's a `max-height` not a fixed height.

**[update] SOLVED thanks to @joel-almeida**
Because the div had a shorted height and hidden overflow it couldn't read the height of the div but with the added .scrollHeight it can read the height of a div no matter if it is visible of hidden.

Comment: Can you throw up a jsfiddle example

Comment: @seth-mcclaine There is a jsfiddle of the Stackoverflow example, but i think its already solved thanks for participating!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why calculating all children height when you can get the parent height straight away ?

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
    var totalHeight = 0;
    totalHeight = $('#parent')[0].scrollHeight;
    alert("Total height of all divs: " + totalHeight);
    $(".clonechild").height(totalHeight);
});
```

```css
#parent {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
#parent .child {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#666;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
#parent .child , .clonechild p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
        #cloneparent {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 300px auto auto 0px;
            width: 510px;
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
        }
        #cloneparent .clonechild {
            float:left;
            min-height:100px;
            height: ;
            width:100px;
            background-color:#666;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            border: 1px solid black;   
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>4</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>5</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>6</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>7</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>8</p></div>
</div>
<p>__#parent clearly not 800px height</p>
<div id="cloneparent">
    <div class="clonechild"><p>this needs to be the same height as #parent</p></div>
    <p>__#cloneparent clearly not same height as #parent</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that does the trick! I assumed u need to have a height set to read it but apparently it can calculate the height of the element without it being set to a number. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: @807 `outerHeight()` gets the **computed** height, so it doesn't matter if you've set it or not, is what the browser renders :)

Comment: After some fiddling i got it to work, it was a little bit difficult because it had a hidden overflow. I got it to work with the '.scrollHeight attribute' changed the code to: 'totalHeight = $('#parent')[0].scrollHeight;' instead of .outerHeight.